How to use python-dotenv for multiple environments
Below is a sample code that works well when we are testing with one environment:
# .env
HOST="https://www.google.com"

# Test.py
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pathlib import Path

dotenv_path = Path('../config/.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=dotenv_path)
hostName = os.getenv('HOST')

print(hostName)


Output: https://www.google.com
Need help in finding a way to set up the same for multiple environments .env.qa, .env.staging, .env.prod, documentation is not clear.
I want to pass the environment name through the command line while executing the file. Do we need to write this logic in separate settings file?

The point of .env files is to locally simulate what will actually be provided in those environments. Don't have .env.qa, set the appropriate env vars in the QA environment.

Have a class or function, that is shared between all environments to get the env data and share it from there could be a solution. This is what we do.

You need to use load_dotenv method
as example:
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
ENVIRONMENT = os.getenv('ENVIRONMENT', 'development')
dotenv_path = f'.env.{ENVIRONMENT}'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path)

you can read more in docs by keyword "load_dotenv"
